# Problem using Jenkins git-repo plugin

Tags: git, jenkins

git 1.9.4 is installed.

Using repo plugin v1.6

When scheduling the build, I got this error message.

fatal: cannot get https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/clone.bundle
fatal: error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable.
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: recommended reading: **[Where does my git question go?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6311/where-does-my-git-question-go)**

Comment: based on the error it appears that it's possibly a network issue.  Can you reach the URL (via `curl`, `wget`, etc) from the jenkins host machine?

Comment: I should have added that when asking the question, but i can use git repo from the command line so the problem is when jenkins tries to use git-repo via the jenkins repo plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to download the file clone.bundle through browser, then save it into a folder and use following command to do repo initialization.

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest --repo-url <path to clone.bundle>
```